# ConstraintLayout, when constraint dependent view is gone, the layout view behave weirdly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm using ConstraintLayout where I will show as below

[image]

I would like to hide `First` (using gone), and which the view I expect to be as below (where ElasticBody will stretch over to use up the original `First` view space as well.

[image]

However, when I actual set `First` to `gone`, my view turn out to be as below (all image as from Android Studio Design view). My `Elastic Body` is missing as well, and the height expanded weirdly.

[image]

My layout code as below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0ff"
        android:text="First"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_body"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#f0f"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Elastic Body"
        android:textSize="26sp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_tail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_tail"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tail"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_body"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

(Note, if you remove the `gone`, you'll get the first image view).
Why is this so? How could I fix it where when my `First` is gone, I could the `Elastic Body` stretch out correctly?

p/s: I know how to do it in LinearLayout and RelativeLayout... but wonder if this is a limitation on ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Dude there's a typo in your code... constraintTop_toBTopOf

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image: See Output :]

**Try following.**

Set the first view's left and top constraints to "parent". After that:

- set the txt_body textview width to "0dp"
- set the left constraint to the first view's right side
- set the right constraint to the tail view's left side.

So, whenever you set the first view's visibility to "gone", the body view will be stretched like how you want it.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0ff"
        android:text="First"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_body"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#f0f"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Elastic Body"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_tail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txt_first"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_tail"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tail"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Update

> If you want to do using barrier then also you can do it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0ff"
        android:text="First"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f0f"
        android:text="Elastic Body"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_tail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_tail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:text="Tail"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="txt_body,txt_first" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="txt_body,txt_tail" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, removing `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_body"` from the `tail` helps. Upvote your answer. Can you elaborate the logic behind? Thanks! (not sure who don't vote, they should at least give a reason... )

Comment: After thinking a while, I think I understand the logic. I ticking yours as the answer. Thanks! (Do upvote my question if you think that helps others)

Comment: The down vote was probably because you said "Try this" and showed a bunch of code. There is no explanation for what you did and you didn't even highlight the lines of code that are meaningful. But then I'm guessing since I didn't do the down vote. So please, add some commentary about what you are suggesting because reading code sucks.

Comment: upvoting it since it is still an answer and effort produced

Answer (score 12):

Say, you want to have a picture like this:

[image]

Here you have indents between the title and "Nice work", between "Nice work" and time, also horizontal indent to "Opinions". They are centered vertically.

[image]

"Opinions" is attached to the star, so that can be multilined and stay centered. I show results for 2 variants: in the first row opinions are multilined, while in the next row it is a single line. In columns you can see 4 variants of showing/hiding 2 labels.

[image]

1. A more simple and preferrable way is to wrap both labels into `LinearLayout` and insert it into parent `ConstraintLayout`. Then you can set vertical gravity, show or hide labels, hide the `LinearLayout` itself.
2. If you don't want to have nested layouts, use `Barrier`s and `Group`s. It is a difficult task that can waste many hours. A key is having additional `View`s for aligning. Here I have 2 hiding labels ("Nice work" and "Opinions"), and I have to add 2 views (spaces).

[image]

The height of the right space is equal to the height of the star (14dp).

To simplify hiding several views, I joined them into groups.

[image]

You can see horizontal dotted lines - they are `Barrier`s. I align them on tops and bottoms of the most big views (barrier_2 is similar):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_text,opinion" />
```

[image]

Vertical aligning is based on these 2 additional `Space`s (see marginTop="10dp"):

```
<Space
    android:id="@+id/left_text_space"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />
```

It is difficult to cover all situations, so see the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="«Title text»"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_text,opinion" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#112233"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Nice work"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left_text_space" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/left_text_space"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/left_text_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_text,left_text_space" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/opinion_space"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_text_space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_text,opinion" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opinion_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_text_space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/opinion_space"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filled_rate_star" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opinion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="1sp"
        android:text="1. Opinion 1.\n2. Opinion 2.\n3. Opinion 3.\n4. Opinion 4."
        android:textColor="#1122aa"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/opinion_icon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/opinion_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/opinion_icon" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/opinion_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="opinion_icon,opinion,opinion_space" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/time_icon"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier_2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="1sp"
        android:lines="2"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:text="17:00"
        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/time_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/time_icon" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in your activity you can show/hide labels. Hide `Group`s, not views inside, because strangely inside a `Group` views are always visible.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

    left_text_group.visibility = View.GONE
    opinion_group.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: is there any way to use image another side of the barrier which is reduce the height of image when text lines are increases

Comment: @ArulMani, sorry, I don't know. Maybe a screenshot will be helpful, but I hardly will create a project.

Answer (score 8):

An answer has already been given linking to [Barriers](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html). I will provide an example of how I've actually implemented it:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:text="Some text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:text="Some other text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1,textView2" />
```

This example shows 2 `TextViews` either of which can be `gone`. The Views are on stacked from top to bottom, so `barrierDirection` is set to `bottom`. Should you need another direction, just change that line accordingly.

Setting any of the 2 `TextViews` to `gone`, will result in the `Barrier` shifting to the bottom of the other, and if we set both to `gone`, it'll just shift up to the element that `textView1`'s top constraint was referencing, in this case, the parent.

> Note: If your `textView1`'s top constraint is something else, i.e. it's below another element, the barrier will end up there if both views are set to `gone`.